How to handle user permission check in next.js - should I cache it server side?
I am implementing user permission checks in my app.
I currently handle user credentials i.e. email, password tokens via Auth0 and I do store user meta data including permissions list in the DB.
I would like check for the users permissions before entering every page AND on inside of the page for at the feature level rather then route level.
I know that I can implement middleware to check for the permissions (look them up in a dictionary and redirect to an "/unauth" endpoint.
My only confusion here is that it mean that I will be making an API call to get this permission wheb entering every page. It sounds like an overhead to me or am I missing something. Should I be caching it server side or inside of my Next js app client side.
My Server is hosted separately and its not an Next.js api routes.
As far as client side caching, am I right thinking that I can just use a library like Tanstack Query and just cache by the key?. Would I then create a User Context that will handle this interanlly?
I am expecting to have permission check at the route level (So if no permissions to enter the page - redirect before the page loads at all) and at the feature level (display page but e.g. disable or hide a button).
I've tried adding middleware to check permissions at the route level but It's calling my api on every page change. I would like to avoid that (if thats a good practice at all).

You might find what I expose in this article useful: a middleware on the backend (so-called "OAuth2 BFF" in the article) is in charge of driving authorization code flow with the authorization server and bridging between session-based authorization and token-based authorization.
As you're using Next.js, this OAuth2 BFF could be implemented with NextAuth (which uses a Node component on the server configured as a confidential client), but even in this case, I prefer using Spring Cloud Gateway with the TokenRelay= filter (easier when scalability, fault tolerance, and observability matter).
Then, what I do is:

the authorization server is in charge of keeping all info about users (including roles)
the BFF authenticates users
a resource server behind the BFF mirrors access token necessary user data (including access expiration time)

In this configuration, the frontend queries the endpoint mirroring user data after login and just before the access expires (this is much more efficient than before each request and just enough to know if a request should be authorized or not based on user roles).
